# "ORA-12899: value too large for column "V_UUID" (actual: 36, maximum: 4000)" when used to generate a Virtual column

Tags: oracle, functions, virtual-columns

I have the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UUID_AS_HEX(bytes IN RAW)
  RETURN CHAR DETERMINISTIC
  IS uuid CHAR(36);
  BEGIN
    RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(bytes, '([0-9A-F]{8})?([0-9A-F]{4})?([0-9A-F]{4})?([0-9A-F]{4})?([0-9A-F]{12})', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5');
  END;
```

and I want to create a virtual column:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
  uuid               RAW(16)                                   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  v_uuid             CHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UUID_AS_HEX(uuid)) VIRTUAL
);
```

throws the following exception:

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column "V_UUID" (actual: 36, maximum: 4000)
```

I tried creating the function with `RETURN CHAR(36) DETERMINISTIC` but it complains about that syntax with

```
2:14:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
; is authid as cluster order using external varying character
```

#### How do I create this function where it match the `CHAR(36)` in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I was able to get it to work by casting the result of the function call:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
  uuid RAW(16)    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  v_uuid CHAR(36) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(UUID_AS_HEX(uuid) AS CHAR(36))) VIRTUAL
);
```